# PHP checkbox zip file download

Tags: php, download, zip

I am using localhost, and I want to download the files from it, selecting multiple files using checkbox, and downloading it to a zip file, I have gone through related questions but it's still not solving the problem.

This is the relevant lines for index page

```
        <form action="download.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="FontFamily.php?id=<?php echo $Font_Family;?>"><?php echo $Font_Family; ?></a></td>
                <td><a href="Font.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a></td>
                <td><img src="Font_Example.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" width="500" height ="100"></td>
                <td align="center" ><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="<?php echo $Font_Name ?>"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Download" ></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

And this is the codes for download.php, the codes are combination of the codes that I found online and here.

```
    <?php
                            $error = ""; //error holder
                            if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
                            {
                            $post = $_POST;
                            $file_folder = "c:\fonts\Arial"; // folder to load files
                            if(extension_loaded('zip'))
                            {
                            // Checking ZIP extension is available
                            if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
                            {
                            // Checking files are selected
                            $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library
                            $zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
                            if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
                            {
                             // Opening zip file to load files
                            $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
                            }
                            foreach($post['files'] as $file)
                            {
                            $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // Adding files into zip
                            }
                            $zip->close();

                            // push to download the zip
                            header('Content-type: application/zip');
                            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                            readfile($zip_name);
                            // remove zip file is exists in temp path


                            }
                            else
                            $error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
                            }
                            else
                            $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
                            }
                            ?>
```

When I download the zip file, the size correct but the file can't be open when I use notepad to open to check the error it shows this

**Warning**:  readfile(1371612622.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\FontLibrary\download.php** on line **29**

Line 29 is

```
    readfile($zip_name);
```

Comment: Looks like a possible permissions problem. Are you sure the Zip file is being created properly? Is it being created where you think it is?

Comment: It is downloaded into default download place set for firefox

Comment: No - the file is created first on the server. It doesn't look like that's happening properly, or possibly not where you expect. Check the server end first.

Comment: I'm sorry how do I check server end? I'm quite new to php...

Comment: Make sure you have error-reporting turned on - see `error_reporting()` in the PHP manual. Then check the error logs after you've run your script to see what shows up. I'm betting that you'll see an `access denied` message because your web server doesn't have permission to write in the directory that it's trying to put the zip file in (which is probably the same folder that your script is in)

Comment: I echo error_reporting(E_ALL) and it show this at the start of the file 32767? Is this the access denied code??

Comment: The value of 32767 is the numerical value of the `error_reporting()` flag. It's not useful. With error reorting turned on you should see any PHP errors and warnings appearing in the web server error log. This is the information you need to debug you script. I can't help you in this area - your server configuration and the location of the log files is something you'll have to work through. Once you have the error log file, fix any problems and ask a new question if you need to.